Incorrect datetime value: ' ' for function str_to_date
In MySQL 5.7, I have a varchar column that has a string datetime that looks like this:
`2024-09-03 02:00:07`

I can run this query:
select date_format(str_to_date(`column1`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%m/%d/%Y')  from table;

This returns the column1 dates in a format that looks like this:
09/03/2024

However when I run this update query:
update table set `column1` = date_format(str_to_date(`column1`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%m/%d/%Y');

I am getting the below error:
Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date

There are some null values in the column.  I updated the structure of the table to DEFAULT: NULL on the column, and I checked the Null checkbox:

How can I fix this so that it will update accordingly?

You may have blank values in that column.  I would convert those to null value.

@shadow - I do see the blank values.  I thought by setting the Default to NULL it would set the blanks as NULL.  Is that not correct?

You may also be able to mess with the sqlmode related to NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, and ALLOW_INVALID_DATES where it might act more gracefully with blank string conversion as outlined in this answer. You can see how MySQL is a little more forgiving at this dbfiddle that has NO_ZERO_IN_DATE and NO ZERO_DATE toggled

"it would set the blanks as NULL. Is that not correct?" No. A blank string is not a NULL and won't be automatically converted to NULL. That checkbox just says that this column will allow NULL values.

Blank value (empty string) is not the same as null.

Check for a blank value before calling the conversion functions.
update table set `column1` = 
    CASE column1
        WHEN '' THEN NULL 
        ELSE date_format(str_to_date(`column1`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%m/%d/%Y')
    END;

